# Working with Microsoft Word VBA - macro to add leading zeroes to date

Tags: vba, date, ms-word, leading-zero

I'm trying to make a macro in Microsoft Word 2013 using VBA to add leading zeroes to dates (mainly dates and months)

So from 4/6/2004 to 04/06/2004
And 5/11/2005 to 05/11/2005

I tried to use a variation of the answer here but it endlessly loops on the first date: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/macro-to-convert-date-format-in-a-document/20539af7-a961-499f-9e85-22af8f4c3c58?auth=1

```
Sub ConvertDateFormat()
Dim FoundOne As Boolean
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory,           Extend:=wdMove
FoundOne = True ' loop at least once
Do While FoundOne ' loop until no     date is found
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "([0-9]{1,2})[/]([0-9]{1,2})[/]([0-9]{4})"
        .Format = True
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute     Replace:=wdReplaceNone
    ' check that the find is a date
If IsDate(Selection.Text) Then
        Selection.Text =      Format(Selection.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy")
        Selection.Collapse     wdCollapseEnd
    Else ' not a date - end loop
        FoundOne = False
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and learn what I have changed.

The art of MS-word find and replace is in Range, collapse and loops(for and do while)

**Working fine on Win-7pro, 64, office 2010, 32**

```
Sub ConvertDateFormat()
With ActiveDocument.Range
    With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "([0-9]{1,2})[/]([0-9]{1,2})[/]([0-9]{4})"
        .Format = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found

    If IsDate(.Text) Then
        .Text = Format(.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    End If
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
    Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, The macro works if Track Changes is off. If I want a solution with track changes on without looping of the first search result - how would I go about that?