# Macro to add leading zeroes to date with Tracking on - Microsoft VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

The following code works without Track Changes on. What changes would have to be made for 'Track Changes' to trigger on macro run and that the script won't keep looping endlessly on the first result?

```
Sub ConvertDateFormat()
With ActiveDocument.Range
With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "([0-9]{1,2})[/]([0-9]{1,2})[/]([0-9]{4})"
    .Format = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Forward = True
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found

If IsDate(.Text) Then
    .Text = Format(.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy")
End If
.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
.Find.Execute
Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Above solution is from:
[Working with Microsoft Word VBA - macro to add leading zeroes to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122915/working-with-microsoft-word-vba-macro-to-add-leading-zeroes-to-date/36123805?noredirect=1#comment59945481_36123805)

Comment: You need to provide detailed information about what this macro should run on, the results it is currently giving you and what the desired result should be. And what do you mean, exactly, by "Track Change to trigger on macro run"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide details in neat. If I understood correctly form your question,

> "script won't keep looping endlessly on the first result",

I think while Track changes are on, words find and replace replaces entire date, so it when you collpse at `.find .execute` there is again the new replaced date so it loops endlessly. You need to add one more .find.execute to skip the new date inserted. I think this will solve the problem.

```
Sub TestTrackOn()
With ActiveDocument.Range
With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "([0-9]{1,2})[/]([0-9]{1,2})[/]([0-9]{4})"
    .Format = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Forward = True
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found
If IsDate(.Text) Then
    .Text = Format(.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy")
End If
.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
.Find.Execute
.Find.Execute
Loop
End With
End Sub
```